# Question about shidduchim and finding your bashert?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, marriage, shidduchim-dating, zivug

I know this is kind of a weird and long-shot question, but are there any Torah sources which mention signs (simanim) that a person is about to find their bashert? And are there are any sources which describe things you can do to speed up the process?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.68.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: If this is a practical question, I strongly suggest not trying to speed it up with segulos. Try instead to learn more about what to look for, how to evaluate potential shidduchim, what to watch out for, and what the other side will be looking for in you. Make yourself a more desirable person while working on developing skills to find the best one you can. And give yourself the time you need. Don't try to rush the process.

Comment: I believe there is a medrash that contrasts Esau and Jacob (who married in his 80s) saying that the righteous marry later.  So you could always avoid being too righteous;) (Of course even Esau married at 40, so...)